# OpenSearch Authentication

Tags: authentication, opensearch

We are trying to integrate our service with SharePoint Search. We have built an OpenSearch endpoint and we have successfully made a search. Now we want to add security using the customers existing username and password (from out service). We have tried setting up basic authentication from SharePoint but we can not see any Authentication headers arriving on our OpenSearch endpoint. Is there any documentation on how SharePoint authenticates OpenSearch or does anyone know how we should do this?

Comment: Did you find some solutions for this ? Thanks,
Alexander.

Comment: No, not yet. There is a bug in SharePoint Online that prevents me from setting authentication. It is currently being investigated by Microsoft